# Display Grouped Product Tier Pricing in Table Columns

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using grouped products with tier pricing and I would like to have each tier in it's own table column. Default display has the columns "Product", "Price", and "Quantity". I would like the columns to be "Product", "Price for 1", "Price for 5", "Price for 100" (etc.), and "Quantity". Is there any way to do this without rewriting pricing from the ground up?

Comment: you mean on the frontend product page ?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the ambiguity.